# Excel function stop after first argument

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help to make formula that based on name and date will place in cell information from another cell.
Everything works until i have same user more than one time. my formula is :
`=IF(AND(G$1>=$B$3:$B$19,G$1<=$C$3:$C$19,MATCH($F3,$A$3:$A$19,0)),$D$3:$D$19,"")`
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mjr4.png)

can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Just suggesting, are values in column D week days initials? Because if you replace those weekdays names with numbers, maybe you may benefit from SUMIFS to get the number associated to a user in specific dates and then use that number in combination with [CHOOSE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) to return D,S or whatever... You just need to create a correlative relation between 1 to something and those initials.

Comment: no in column d is a notification like s- sick

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the `FILTER`-Formula:

`=FILTER($D$3:$D$19,($F3=$A$3:$A$19)*(G$1>=$B$3:$B$19)*(G$1<=$C$3:$C$19),"")`

"old school":

`=IFNA(INDEX($D$3:$D$19,MATCH(1,($F3=$A$3:$A$19)*(G$1>=$B$3:$B$19)*(G$1<=$C$3:$C$19),0)),"")`

Comment: saddly i dont use 365 thats why i have to find other way

Comment: updated with formula that will work with any Excel version

Comment: Old school also didnt work , if i use it shows always ifna gives always " " so i have only empty cells not as should from column D

Comment: Did you check the columns? Maybe my setting was not correct?

Comment: yes i checked but i dont understand why in match you search for 1 ?

Comment: if all three conditions are true, 1 is returned, if at least one is wrong 0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach? Use numbers instead of letters and create a secondary dataset where each number is related to a letter. Then VLOOKUP the result there;

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(SUMIFS($D$12:$D$17,$B$12:$B$17,"<="&G$10,$C$12:$C$17,">="&G$10,$A$12:$A$17,$F12),$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)
```

Not the cleanest one but it works in old versions of Excel...

Notice in cell A2 There is a 0 value associated to a blank value. To avoid the formula returning zeros you must deactivate option:

> [Display or hide zero
> values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03)

Comment: This method works but still preffered to dont use numbers but if i cant find solution then probably i have to use it